# AEM XPATH Query issue with single quote

Tags: xpath, full-text-search, aem, single-quotes

My application runs a query created using  querybuilder API but finally, its converted into an XPath query and executed.  Everything works well except when there is a quote symbol in the text.
I ma using custom predicates to search the text. Example:
`predicateMap.put("0_group.2_group.title_customcase.title_fulltext", searchText)`;

I tried this in the native interface at http://localhost:4502/crx/explorer/ui/search.jsp and it fails there as well.

```
Search for: don't
Search in: /content/geometrixx/en
XPath Query generated: /jcr:root/content/geometrixx/en//*[jcr:contains(., 'don't')] order by @jcr:score descending
```

Exception (similar to my server logs):

```
Error: javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException: java.text.ParseException:
```

Is there any workaround for this?  I did find some similar questions on SoF but not the exact thing.
The querydebug page is able to search this text but it just seems to replace it with 2 quotes:

```
/jcr:root/content/geometrixx/en//*[jcr:contains(., 'don''t')]
```

So I am confused why such behavior withing AEM itself.

Comment: Could you post the code where you use the `QueryBuilder` to add this predicate?

Comment: Can you try hexadecimal value for quote. May be it will help you.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar, I've tried using "%27" instead of the single quote, but it breaks down the whole code. Didn't work in the query debugger as well.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz, I've added the line of code in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are always two escape mechanisms you have to keep in mind:

1) escaping a character within the contains statement. e.g. the spec says you 
can search for a phrase using double quotes: "foo bar". that means if you want 
to use a double quote as literal an not a delimiter for a phrase you have to 
escape it.

2) escaping any string literal appropriately in XPath or SQL. E.g. in XPath the 
string literal must not be written as: 'don"t'

for your query that means you have to write: 
**/jcr:root/content/geometrixx/en//*[jcr:contains(., 'don\"t')] order by @jcr:score descending**

OR

you can use double quot 
**/jcr:root/content/geometrixx/en//*[jcr:contains(., "don't")] order by @jcr:score descending**